# Get host name from IP address on network using JAVA

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, hostname, inetaddress

I am trying to find out the information of all connected client in my network. I am able to find out the client(is reachable) but can't fetch information about him. I need only the host name(computer name), but following code only print the IP address. What i am missing?

## source

```
private void getListOfHost(){
     String subnet="192.168.0";
     int timeout=100;
     for (int i=2;i<15;i++){
         String host=subnet + "." + i;
         try {
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
                 InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                 System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                 System.out.println("Canonical host: " + address.getCanonicalHostName());
                 System.out.print("Host name: " + address.getHostName() + "\n");
            }
         }
         catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

## output

```
192.168.0.6 is reachable
Canonical host: 192.168.0.6
Host name: 192.168.0.6
```

Comment: Do you have a local DNS server serving authoritative records for that subnet and is it configured correctly? Does `nslookup 192.168.0.6` work?

Comment: Which OS are you currently on?

Comment: I am calling this code from android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything in the code,but,the source of error is the ***security manager/firewall of the called system***.

The Oracle docs for the [InetAddress.getCanonicalHostname()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) states that :-

**Returns:**

> the fully qualified domain name for this IP address, or if the
>   operation is not allowed by the security check, the textual
>   representation of the IP address.

The Oracle docs for the [InetAddress.getHostname()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName()) states that :-

**Returns:**

> the host name for this IP address, or if the operation is not allowed
>   by the security check, the textual representation of the IP address.

**Solution :-**

Whatever system you want to enquire host-name of,just disable the firewall of that system. The security managers will always block system-specific enquiries about the other systems in the network as it is considered not an information to be shared(unsecure). ***You should always keep this thing in mind.***

Comment: Another possibility might be you don't have a `dns-server` configured for that client's domain name. Instead it only uses IP-Address for communication. In that case, you need to set up a nameserver for that client/add its hostname entry.